# Справка по синтаксису команды @@include

Tags: javascript, html, веб-программирование, gulp, синтаксис

Нашел ресурс [Самые простые способы интеграции HTML](https://www.internet-technologies.ru/articles/samye-prostye-sposoby-integracii-html.html)
. В нем в разделе **Используем Gulp** используется команда `@@include`. Искал справку по синтаксису данной команды, но не нашел. Дайте ссылку на справку по **синтаксису** `@@include` (от каких аргументов зависит и т.д.).

Comment: Там рядом ссылка есть https://github.com/haoxins/gulp-file-include